# Clear angular form validation after correcting entry by updating $scope model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a field thus:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20" required ng change="checkUsername()">
<p ng-show="username_taken"  class="help-block">This username is taken.  
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="suggestUsername()">Shall we suggest one?</a></p>
```

After the user clicks on Shall we suggest?, the suggestUsername() function is called and populates the username ($scope.user.username) with a unique username, which updates the model, but the form validation $valid state is not cleared.

How do I tell angular to re-validate the form after I have updated its model?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: form.$setPristine sets the form to its initial unvalidated state, try that.

Comment: Thx - doesn't work for some reason.  $scope.userSignup.$setValidity();                 $scope.userSignup.$setPristine();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $setPristine() to the form

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Example:

Your html:

```
<form name="yourFormName" id="form" novalidate>
   <!-- your form controls here -->
</form>
```

Your controller:

```
// set to pristine, ONLY clears CSS styling, etc...
$scope.yourFormName.$setPristine();

// update your model values as well
```

Comment: Thx - doesn't work for some reason.       `$scope.userSignup.$setValidity();
                $scope.userSignup.$setPristine();`

Comment: you mean, the form input control styles still indicates that the form is invalid?

Comment: It worked once I declared my form model in $scope.  `ng-min` was causing the model object not to get instantiated until its criteria was satisfied, which I'm guessing I did not handle in my test.